# Create a List Item whenever an Item is created in differnet list using Nintex Workflows

Tags: 2013, workflow

I am using SharePoint 2013, Nintex 2013 Workflow.

Basically, I want to add the List items from one list to another list using Nintex Workflows.

Let us consider our source List as List1 & destination List as List2.

List1 has 4 columns: Name, DOB, Telephone, Address

List2 has 2 columns: Name, DOB

Now, I want, the two columns Name and DOB to be auto populated in List2 whenever an entry is made in List1.

How can I do this using Nintex Workflows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be acheived using OOTB Sharepoint Designer workflows as well if both the lists are in same site. You have to create a List workflow and add a action "Create List Item" , configure the action to map the columns whose value needs to be same.

http://blogs.salmanghani.info/create-item-workflow-sharepoint-designer-2010/

The same steps are available in Nintex workflow as well.

If you are trying to add a list item in different site see below link:
http://connect.nintex.com/forums/thread/6132.aspx

Comment: Now, suppose I have 2 additional columns to List2. Here, I don want to make changes to the auto populated columns from List1. Is there any way to make those fields read only or completely invisible from the UI?

Comment: In List2 there can be same no of columns or different no of columns. You have to just map the columns which needs to be same in both the lists. The other columns in List2 can be kept blank or some other default value can be inserted depending on your need.

Comment: I have tried out the workflow. It works like a charm. But, I don't want the auto populated columns in List2 to be edited. The adding/editing of those two columns should be through List1 only. So, I don want them in the add new item/edit item form of List2.

Comment: Is the columns added to list directly or through Content type?You can make the fields hidden in forms.You can do this pro grammatically as well as from the List settings only if you have added the columns to the List through content type.

Comment: It worked. I added the columns through a content type. Then, made all the columns to Hidden which ever I didn't want to display in New and Edit form.